# Transfer of inventory and EXP from crashed world to new world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-hexxit

So I had a world I was doing pretty great on. My computer suddenly turned off due to low battery, which caused that world to become corrupt. I have been able to transfer the world itself to a "new world" via copying the region folder from the original world to the new world. My problem is I haven't been able to successfully restore my inventory and XP (been playing on HC and I was pretty proud of how long I've survived).

I have looked many places and they all say to transfer the `level.dat` files (I am assuming this means `level.dat_mcr`, `level.dat_old`, file that is named simply "levels" but is a DAT file). I have also heard that you should also transfer `session.lock`, and the "player" folder.

When I transfer all of these the new world the file will not show up on the load screen. From my tests it happens as soon as I drop in the file named "level" that is a DAT file. I was wondering if it may be that the level file is corrupt (and if so how can I fix it? The file won't open in NBTexplorer) or if I'm just not supposed to transfer that.
I am working with Minecraft 1.5.2 and its pretty much Hexxit with like 2 additional mods.

Answer (score 1):

`level.dat` will be where, on singleplayer, your player data is stored (along with a few other things like world seed). If you open it up, it's likely that it's blank now.

`level.dat_old` should be a backup of `level.dat`. If you still have that, try copying it to your new world folder and renaming it to `level.dat` (replacing the `level.dat` in your new world folder).

I'd recommend backing up the files you have currently before you do much more. For example, if you have moved the `level.dat_old` to the new world folder then continued to play on the new world, then your `level.dat_old` will have been overwritten by the new `level.dat`.